# What does「あればっかりは見た方が早いですって」​mean in this context ? (A conversation of MC, eating lunch with his office colleagues in a coffee shop )

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english, video-games

[image]

Context: MC is having lunch with his office's colleagues, inside a coffee shop. They're talking about the shop owner. The MC asked "Does she handle everything in this shop alone?" Then one of his colleagues said "No, there are other part-time girls working here too".

After this there is one sentence which I don't understand, so many thanks if anyone can explain to me its meaning or correct my understanding if I was wrong.

> MC「この店、店長がひとりでやってるんですか？」
> 吉野「バイトの子も何人かいるよ。出来れば見せてあげたかったんだけどね」
> MC「吉野さんの知り合いとかですか？」
> 吉野「いや、ぜんぜん。顔なじみといえば顔なじみだけどね」
> **千倉「あればっかりは見た方が早いですって」** (my guess :"I heard people says that a direct meeting  would be faster to know someone ,instead of just describing with words like you did."  )

> ふたりの口ぶりからして、看板娘みたいな子でもいるんだろうか。
> 個人的には、あの店長も充分に個性的な感じがするんだけど。

Answer (score 2):

見た方が早い means "It's faster to see it/him/her (than to be explained with words)". This is a common phrase used when something is difficult to explain but easy to understand if you actually see it. あればっかりは here means "At least as far as that (person) is concerned", "At least on this matter". Describing a person as 見た方が早い is unusual, so he added it to avoid sounding lazy or impolite. So あればっかりは見た方が早い implies this バイトの子 is someone who stands out in appearance and is hard to explain in some way or another.

Comment: is this a short version of this idiom ? 実際見たほうが早い  or 百聞は一見にしかず (" one time witness with your own eyes is better than thousand times of hearsays" ?)

Comment: @casualreader 百聞は一見にしかず is a common idiom with a similar meaning, but (実際)見た方が速い is not an idiom or an abbreviated version of something.